# Facebook marketing api: Is is possible to manage custom audience for a client?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I have to integrate facebook custom audience apis with my application which handles users fb marketing.

After I log the user in to get the access token with all the relevant permissions like ads_read,ads_management and business_managment.

I am getting an error while trying to fetch the custom audiences for the client

> type: OAuthException, code: 272, message: (#272) This Ads API call
>   requires the user to be admin of the application. User is not admin or
>   developer of this application., x-fb-trace-id: H6HzozvlbXp [HTTP 400]

Am I missing something in this or does facebook not allow for such a scenario or is it because the app is in development mode.

P.S I did try to add another admin https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/ but no option for an app in the same.

Comment: Adding developers to an app is done via the app dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

While in development mode, you'll need the users to be admins of your app. Go to developers.facebook.com, select your App from the drop down on the top right. Click Roles on the menu on the right. Add the user as an admin. You may also need to add the ad account under Settings->Advanced->Authorized Account IDs.